# How to access ReactContextBaseJavaModule from both, a react native file (*.js) and a Kotlin class (*.kt)?

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, react-native-native-module, react-native-modules

I am new to React Native and working on an application which stores local data using Android SharedPreferences. I currently have SharedPreferences setup as `ReactContextBaseJavaModule` and am able to access all methods through `@ReactMethod` annotation from a React Native file.

I need to access the value from SharedPreference, defined as `ReactContextBaseJavaModule`, inside native Android module. Currently I am able to achieve that by updating a constant defined in native Android class(*.kt). Is there a better way to do this, i.e. ability to access methods defined inside `ReactContextBaseJavaModule` from Android classes or creating a wrapper for SharedPreference access?

I have tried to search for the solution in multiple platforms, and found solutions on how we can access native module from React Native files. I am unable to find the solution on two-way access to a `ReactContextBaseJavaModule` class.

The challenges I am facing:

1. Unable to pass `ReactApplicationContext` from native Android class for the class instance.
2. Unable to access methods annotated with `@ReactMethod` from native Android class.
3. Injecting native Android class instance inside `ReactContextBaseJavaModule`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Created a native android `SharedPreferences` class that exposes all the shared preferences related methods.

   class MySharedPreferences constructor(context: Context) {/**getters and setters**/}
2. Created a `ReactContextBaseJavaModule` as a bridge to React Native with exposed methods annotated with `@ReactModule`. Created an instance of Android native `SharedPreferences` inside `init{}` method.

   ```
    class MySharedPreferencesModule(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext) : ReactContextBaseJavaModule(reactContext) {
     private var mySharedPreferences: BeaconSharedPreferences

    init {
        mySharedPreferences = MySharedPreferences(context = reactContext)
    }}
   ```
3. Now I am able to access Android native `SharedPreferences` with an instance inside the Android class where I need to access the prefs values, and access/update values through the bridge to/from React Native.